# Maven-Failure to transfer

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am very new to maven,I integrated maven in eclipse and when I am trying convert my existing
project into maven I am getting following error:

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution
will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates 
are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-
plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

I have no idea what is this? please guide me.

Comment: Run command with -e so that you see the exceptions. Then please paste here a bigger part of the build log, not only 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependency on the maven-surefire-plugin could not be downloaded.

Verify that your maven is set up correctly (proxy is configured) and retry getting the dependencies using the maven -U command line parameter.

If the problem persists, try debugging the maven flow using the -X command line parameter.